# input pin not working

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, input-device

I connected the 3v3 power pin to a switch and then to an IO pin set to input. when I turned on the switch, it works fine and I detect an input, but when I turned off the switch, it was going back and forth from on and off. Why is this? also, I am using RPi.GPIO

Comment: This Question is too vague. You need to specify what you have connected more clearly - your description is subject to many interpretations. You also need to explain HOW you are reading it.

Comment: Still vague. "using RPi.GPIO" is meaningless - you should list code.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following.

[image]

See https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits